# Can't get access to the field "title",when I'm trying to acces via field of a array

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Can't get access to the field "title", when I'm trying to access it via the field of an array. So, guys, I'm trying to get access to the field Title, for instance, ShellContent1_2.Title, instead of writing like ShellContent1_2.Title,ShellContent2_2.Title... I'm using arrays and cycle for.
Please help me. Thanks.

```
namespace RakeshProj;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
public partial class AppShell: Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Extensions.JsonRead(@"C:\Users\Matsenko\source\repos\TestJson\TestJson\appsettings.json");
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings`.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
        //Menu menu_settings = config.GetSection("ShellContentNames").Get<Menu>();
        //CounterLabel.Title = "Hey";
        //SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterLabel.Title);  
        string[][] ShellContentNames= 
        {
        new string[3]
        {
            "ShellContent1_1","ShellContent2_1","ShellContent3_1"
        },
        new string[12]
        {
                 "ShellContent1_2","ShellContent2_2","ShellContent3_2",
                 "ShellContent4_2","ShellContent5_2","ShellContent6_2",
                 "ShellContent7_2","ShellContent8_2","ShellContent9_2",
                 "ShellContent10_2","ShellContent11_2","ShellContent12_2"
        }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < ShellContentNames.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < ShellContentNames[j].Length; j++)
            {
                ShellContentNames[i][j].Title = "Hey";
                SemanticScreenReader.Announce(ShellContentNames[i][j].Title);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: string does not have a field or property called Title.

Comment: hijinxbassist how can I fix it?

Comment: Remove `.Title`

Comment: hijinxbassist Check my second screenshot

Comment: ShellContentNames contains only strings.  string does not have Title.  Perhaps you meant to use a different data type?  In the comments in your second screenshot, the data is clearly not string, since it does have a property/field called Title.  It might be a Label or something else, no real way for us to know.

Comment: Yep,you are right.Сan I convert the string to the same type like in the second screenshot?hijinxbassist

Comment: Probably not.  It depends on what that other type is.  primitive types can be expressed as strings and converted back and forth. Complex types would require special initialization logic.

Comment: Okay,thanks,but can I do it other way,if yes, say please tell me how 
hijinxbassist

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details, including what you are trying to do.  Without more detailed information, this question will be closed for lacking details.

Comment: why is this tagged `asp.net`?  This appears to be a very basic C# question

Comment: @Jason for faster reply

Comment: please don't abuse the site just for your convenience.  Take the time to read [ask] before posting again.

Comment: @hijinxbassist check the edited question

Comment: @Jason sorry man, I understand you,but I need the fastest reply I can get

Comment: @Jason I'm trying my best,just help me please if it possible

Comment: we can't help you because we have no idea what you're trying to do.  `string` does not have a "field" named "Title".  A `string` is just a `string`.   What you are asking makes no sense.  The fact that you're in a hurry is not our problem.

Comment: Think you've reached the point where you need a more sophisticated data storage device. Toss out the nested arrays in favor of a pair of classes, where one has a list of the other, for example

Comment: Determine the type you are using.  We do not know what data type has Title.  Once you determine the appropriate type, change the string[] to myType[] and put the actual objects in the array.  What you are attempting is akin to "ConfigurationBuilder".AddJsonFile(..)  which of course won't work, since string does not have a method called AddJsonFile.

Comment: `var page = new ContentPage();  page.Title = "blah";`  this works because `page` is an **instance of the ContentPage class**, and that class has a `property` named `Title`.  `var page = "ContentPage";` just creates a `string` with the value "ContentPage".  They are **completely different** things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Jason wrote in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72048924/cant-get-access-to-the-field-title-when-im-trying-to-acces-via-field-of-a-ar/72049601#comment127307981_72048924) (formatting added for readability):

> ```
> var page = new ContentPage(); 
> page.Title = "blah";
> ```
>
> This works because `page` is an instance of the `ContentPage` class, and
> that class has a property named `Title`.
>
> ```
> var page = "ContentPage";
> ```
>
> This just creates a string with the value `ContentPage`. They are completely different things.

In my case, I need to use `ShellContent` instead of `ContentPage`.